# yii2 - как найти все значения в таблице БД по трем последним символам?

Tags: yii2, запрос, find, where

Так можно сделать?

Можно ли как-то в Yii2 написать запрос к БД, который находит все значения по трем последним символам строки в колонке таблице?

Вот в примере, найдутся все строки таблицы, у которых в колонке 'CODE' 000.
Test::find()->where(['CODE' => '000'])->all();

А нужно, чтобы нашлись все строки, у которых в колонке 'CODE' 000 - были тремя последними символами.

Так можно сделать?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это строка, то можно попробовать так:

```
Test::find()->where(['LIKE', 'CODE', '%000'])->all();
```

Answer (score -1):

Для решения задачи подойдет метод yii\db\ActiveRecord::findBySql():

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#findBySql()-detail

Как-то так:

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Test SUBSTRING(CODE, -3) IN (000)';

Test::findBySql($sql)->all();